# Div with a blue background colour, is being displayed as shaded on some machines using IE8

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have the following Div inside my sharePoint 2013 web site:-

```
<div class="ms-comm-adminLinks ms-core-defaultFont ms-noList" unselectable="on"> 
  <div class="ms-webpart-titleText" unselectable="on"> Useful Links </div> 
  <ul class="ms-comm-adminLinksList" unselectable="on"> 

<ul unselectable="on">
//code goes here..
  <li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href=
 </ul>
</ul>
```

And I define this inside my custom css file:-

```
.ms-comm-adminLinks {
    background-color:#008CD2 !important;
    }
```

Currently the background color will be shown well on firefox,chrome, safari, IE9 and above.
But some users who are using IE8 on some machine  (not all users using IE8 have the problem), will see this background color as if it has been shaded, as follow:-
[image]

While other users using IE 8 and above or using safari,chrome , firefox, can see the background color as follow without any problem:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where you able to click the links, if not it looks like the div goes beyond some other div with transparency. Use zindex for that div

Comment: you mean to access it live ? if so no as it is part of an intranet?

Comment: can you post on jsfiddle

Comment: not sure if it is possible, as i am using some code that is specifically for sharePoint , so it will not work on jsfiddle!!

Comment: did u face similat problem on IE7 and IE8

Comment: yes i faced the same problem on IE browsers. May be you can try this give position:relative to ms-comm-adminLinks ie is parent of that blue div and z-index as 9999

Comment: very sorry can't help you without actual coding, but very sure this can be solved.

Comment: and i am unable to post the code as many functionalities depends on some SharePoint libraries that can not be added insdie the jsfiddle..